# Ubuntu USB Expert Install - Grub2 installs on USB

Tags: grub2, live-usb, ubuntu-minimal

I used Unetbootin and Installed the mini.iso over to my USB. I carried out the wizard installation steps and Grub2 gets installed onto the USB Stick instead of the Hard Drive. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to a computer already running Ubuntu, try the Startup Disc Creator. It's optimized for Ubuntu.